# Move Azure CosmosDB to local environment

Tags: azure, graph, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

hope you are doing great!

Right now, we are developing a web app with .NET CORE in dev environment, does mean that our config file is pointing to Azure CosmosDB, and we use Gremlin to manage Graph stuff.

But what we need also, is to make a local environment but we dont know how to have the CosmosDB in our local PC's.

Does anyone know a tool or something to get CosmosDB, with Graph supports and Gremlin working locally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Cosmos DB Emulator can be installed locally for local development purposes, however, the emulator does not support the Gremlin API for Graph storage.

While you cannot use Cosmos DB locally, you could install another database that supports the Gremlin API locally for your local Dev environments; such as the [Apache Tinkerpop Gremlin Server](http://tinkerpop.apache.org). If you do this, then you'll want to extra make sure you fully test your code against Cosmos DB Graph API, before deploying to ensure that there aren't any compatibility issues when releasing to Testing, Staging, and eventually Production environments.

Comment: Thanks! We will try this out with Tinkerpop then.

Comment: Also, other question, Im new to this tool. Gremlin server also provides you a local graph database? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no emulator that will allow you to work with the Gremlin API locally. You're going to have to provision a development instance within Azure, or perhaps one per developer on your team.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Cosmos DB Emulator now supports graph databases. The management UI doesn't support Gremlin but only SQL but you can use it in your program via Gremlin.

It's described in https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli,ssl-netstd21#gremlin-api